Uneven distribution of consumed messages per consumer inside same consumer group for Kafka
I have to consume messages from a topic on a Kafka cluster with 10 partitions where messages are being evenly distributed accros them. I have a ASP.NET application with 10 background services where each service fires up a consumer (Confluent.Kafka 2.6.1) so that I can process messages from each partition in parallel. For now, I'm not doing any real processing so that is not affecting the time to consume new messages.
The issue that I'm having is that some of my consumers go way ahead with the number of messages consumed from their partition. For example, the consumer with the highest message count has consumed around 17000 messages, while the consumer with the lowest number of messages has consumed only 1500 in a similar time span of 3 minutes.
I've played with various settings on the consumer configuration, but without any noticeable difference. Here is my latest configuration try:
new ConsumerConfig
{
    ClientId = options.Operator,
    BootstrapServers = options.GetKafkaBootstrapServers(),
    GroupId = options.GetKafkaGroupId(),
    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Ssl,
    SslCaLocation = options.Kafka.Ssl.CaLocation,
    SslCertificateLocation = options.Kafka.Ssl.CertificateLocation,
    SslKeyLocation = options.Kafka.Ssl.KeyLocation,
    EnableAutoOffsetStore = false,
    ConsumeResultFields = "none",
    PartitionAssignmentStrategy = PartitionAssignmentStrategy.CooperativeSticky
};

that produced these results:
partition: average (total message count / elapsed seconds)
--------------------
0: 16 (3000 / 180)
1: 14 (2600 / 185)
2: 89 (16900 / 189)
3: 28 (5300 / 187)
4: 24 (4500 / 185)
5: 56 (10400 / 185)
6: 8 (1500 / 180)
7: 21 (4100 / 194)
8: 28 (5200 / 181)
9: 12 (2200 / 178)

Is there anything on the consumer side that I can do to balance this out? I don't have control over the kafka cluster, but I might suggest something to the company owning the cluster if that will help with this.
Thank you

is there any lag?

Does the producer specify a partitioning key when adding messages to the topic? What is the key, exactly? An integer? A string? A GUID? Something else?

@IvanPetrov Yes, when I start consuming there is a lag on all partitions (around 100 000 messages)

@AlexeyAdadurov The producer specifies the partitioning key and it is a string that consists of two GUIDs separated by the underscore sign.

@BorisMarković, you may find this page useful: https://www.confluent.io/en-gb/learn/kafka-partition-key/ , and it clearly mentions what could be done to avoid 'hot' partitions. I suggest following the guide. 1) Understand the use cases for partitioning, 2) Choosing the key that ensures sufficiently even distribution of hash values while conforming to other (business) requirements. Thus, I'd question the need to use 2 concatenated GUIDs as the key, and would definitely want to test them against the murmur hash function that Kafka uses for hashing keys.

Of course, the above only makes sense if the impact of the uneven balance is high enough that it must definitely be addressed and just couldn't be left as-is.

@AlexeyAdadurov Thanks for the link to the documentation, I'll take a look at it. Yeah, maybe the uneven balance is not an issue as it will balance itself after the lag is processed and the consumers catch up, I just need to implement proper business logic while the consumers are catching up.
